# Definition of permutations of a set

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm reading some lecture notes on group theory, and I don't fully understand their definition of the permutations of a set. Given a set $S$, it defines $\mathrm{Perm}(S)$ as the set of one-to-one maps from $S$ to $S$.

The problem I'm having is that the maps are only required to be one-to-one. If $f \in \mathrm{Perm}(S)$, I need to be able to find a two-sided inverse $g$ so that $f \circ g = g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$, but it admits a right inverse only if it's surjective. The only conclusion I can reach is that it must be the case that such a map is automatically surjective and hence bijective. That is certainly true for finite sets, but is it also true for infinite sets? I'm having difficulty proving that. If $S = \{1, \ldots, n\}$, then this result is fine, for example.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It is not true that injective implies surjective for infinite sets.  The map $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ defined by $n\mapsto 2n$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: I have never seen permutations defined via injections, only via bijections.

Comment: No, the definition should be, that the symmetric group  ${\rm Sym}(X)$ is the set of all bijections $f\colon X\rightarrow X$. Perhaps "one-to-one" is a wrong translation from other languages to English. Can you give a link, where you have found this definition? Which lecture notes on group theory do you refer to?

Comment: People truly need to stop using those expressions. How is one supposed to remember which is which between "one-one" and "one-to-one"?

Comment: Sure it doesn't say "one-to-one maps from $S$ **onto** $S$"?

Comment: @CaptainLama: there is no difference between "one-one" and "one-to-one".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It doesn't say that, but it seems to me that it should be precisely that. I was worried I was missing something about the definition.